# What is the correct name of the element to change it's CSS properties after link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a horizontal scrolling date selector (which is working fine). What I am trying to accomplish is when the user clicks on a date link it will fire a jquery click event (which is successful) and then I would like the css properties of the clicked link to change to the last two entries in my css file. Apparently I do not know how to properly address the name for the clicked link because everything I try does nothing. The a:active attribute will temporarily apply the correct css when you mousedown on the element but as soon as the click is over it goes back. I have also tried the a:visited to no avail. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```js
$("#datePicker a").click(function(event) {
     var date = this.getAttribute("data-date");
     alert('date');
     //future events here
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#datecontainer {
  background-color: #a07a3d;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
#datecontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 620px;
  z-index: 0;
}
div.moviedatediv div.dates #date-scroller:after {
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.moviedatediv {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto-bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 76px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 92px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.moviedatediv a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.moviedatediv a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.moviedatediv a span.date {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto-condensed-bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
}
#datePicker #datecontainer a:active {
  background-color: #d49f38;
  height: 76px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 92px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#datePicker #datecontainer a:after {
  border-top: 5px solid #d49f38;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dates" id="datePicker">
    <div id="datecontainer" class="slider responsive">
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-19" href="#">Tue <span class="date">19</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-20" href="#">Wed <span class="date">20</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-21" href="#">Thu <span class="date">21</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-22" href="#">Fri <span class="date">22</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-23" href="#">Sat <span class="date">23</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-24" href="#">Sun <span class="date">24</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-25" href="#">Mon <span class="date">25</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-26" href="#">Tue <span class="date">26</span>February</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add active color to clicked date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to add same style as you are done for `a:active` for clicked date, the change `#datePicker #datecontainer a:active` to `#datePicker #datecontainer a:active, #datePicker #datecontainer a.active`. And add a active class for clicked element.

```js
$("#datePicker a").click(function(event) {
  var date = this.getAttribute("data-date");
  alert('date '+date);
  $(this).closest('#datecontainer').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //future events here
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#datecontainer {
  background-color: #a07a3d;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}

#datecontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 620px;
  z-index: 0;
}

div.moviedatediv div.dates #date-scroller:after {
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.moviedatediv {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto-bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 76px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 92px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.moviedatediv a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.moviedatediv a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.moviedatediv a span.date {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto-condensed-bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
}

#datePicker #datecontainer a:active, #datePicker #datecontainer a.active {
  background-color: #d49f38;
  height: 76px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 92px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#datePicker #datecontainer a:after {
  border-top: 5px solid #d49f38;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dates" id="datePicker">
  <div id="datecontainer" class="slider responsive">
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-19" href="#">Tue <span class="date">19</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-20" href="#">Wed <span class="date">20</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-21" href="#">Thu <span class="date">21</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-22" href="#">Fri <span class="date">22</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-23" href="#">Sat <span class="date">23</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-24" href="#">Sun <span class="date">24</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-25" href="#">Mon <span class="date">25</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
      <a data-date="2019-02-26" href="#">Tue <span class="date">26</span>February</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hadn't even thought about needing the line of code to clear the active css element if the user changes to another date.

Comment: Ok, if you need it you can use. otherwise remove it. I thought that there will be only a active one.

Comment: You are correct. I will definitely need that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a css class to the `a` tag using jquery.

Jquery to add a class on the clicked `a` tag. When the user clicked any link in your datepicker, `$(this).addClass('active')` will add the `active` class to the `a` tag.

```
$("#datePicker a").click(function(event) {
     var date = this.getAttribute("data-date");
     $(this).addClass('active');
     alert('date');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

CSS

```
.active {
  background-color: #d49f38;
  height: 76px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 92px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#datePicker a").click(function(event) {
     var date = this.getAttribute("data-date");
     var ele = $(event.target);
     ele.css('background-color', '#d49f38');//add style
     ele.addClass("active");//add class
     alert(event.target.value);
     //future events here
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#datecontainer {
  background-color: #a07a3d;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
#datecontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 620px;
  z-index: 0;
}
div.moviedatediv div.dates #date-scroller:after {
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.moviedatediv {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto-bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 76px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 92px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.moviedatediv a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.moviedatediv a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.moviedatediv a span.date {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto-condensed-bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
}
#datePicker #datecontainer a:active {
  background-color: #d49f38;
  height: 76px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 92px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#datePicker #datecontainer a:after {
  border-top: 5px solid #d49f38;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dates" id="datePicker">
    <div id="datecontainer" class="slider responsive">
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-19" href="#">Tue <span class="date">19</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-20" href="#">Wed <span class="date">20</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-21" href="#">Thu <span class="date">21</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-22" href="#">Fri <span class="date">22</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-23" href="#">Sat <span class="date">23</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-24" href="#">Sun <span class="date">24</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-25" href="#">Mon <span class="date">25</span>February</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moviedatediv">
     <a data-date="2019-02-26" href="#">Tue <span class="date">26</span>February</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```